# dbatools, DbcCheck Does not use Saved credential

Tags: sql-server, dbatools, dbachecks

Last week I deployed **dbccheck** on the production environment. I found strange thing and have no idea what the problem is.
We have 40 db vm's which are not domain joined. Each of db vm's have same windows login credential and DB with sql server authentication having sysadmin privilege and
are configured as below.

`Set-DbcConfig -Name policy.storage.backuppath -Value \\backup\userfull`

`Set-DbcConfig -Name app.sqlinstance -Value 10.1.1.1`

`Set-DbcConfig -Name app.computername -Value DB-22`

`Set-DbcConfig -Name app.sqlcredential  (Get-Credential Username)`

`Set-DbcConfig -Name policy.ola.userfullretention -value 47`

Whenever I run the below command with manually passed credentials, it works fine but if I remove the `(-SqlCredential (Get-Credential username))` and run.
it fails.

`Invoke-DbcCheck   backuppathaccess, UserFull,FailedJob, olainstalled, Storage -SqlCredential (Get-Credential username) -Show Summary -PassThru | Update-DbcPowerBiDataSource -Environment Production Start-DbcPowerBi`

[image: Running Invoke-DbcCheck backuppathaccess, UserFull,FailedJob, olainstalled, Storage]

I need to run without providing credential manually.

It looks like the dbachecks module is up to date:

[image: Dbachecks Version]

Comment: Did you pass the SQL Server authentication credentials to the Invoke-DbcCheck command?

Comment: yes, Passing SQL Server authentication credentials to Invoke-DBccheck works perfectly, but i want to avoid passing credential every time i need report. I need it to work without passing SQL Server authentication Credential even though i have save 
 Credential using   `Set-DbcConfig -Name app.sqlcredential  (Get-Credential Username)` . , I need BI report by only running this `Invoke-DbcCheck   backuppathaccess, UserFull,FailedJob, olainstalled, Storage` .............................I would be grateful if have idea or suggestion regarding this.

Comment: To run Invoke-DbcCheck without manually passing the SQL Server authentication credentials, you need to store the credentials in an encrypted form in a secure location, and then retrieve them in your script when needed. This can be done using the Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI). Try that.